# Error in case Haskell

Tags: haskell, case

I have to do a software to identify tokens in C. I have this code:

```
*main = do
   x <- readFile "progc.c"
   let resultado = lexCmm X
   print resultado
lexCmm :: String -> [Tok]
  lexCmm X = case X of
    c:cs   | isSpace c     -> lexCmm cs
    c:cs   | isAlpha c     -> getId s
    c:cs   | isDigit c     -> getInt s
    c:d:cs | isSymb [c,d]  -> TS [c,d] : lexCmm cs
    c:cs   | isSymb [c]    -> TS [c]   : lexCmm cs
    _                      -> []  
   where
    getId s  = lx i : lexCmm cs where (i,cs) = span isIdChar s
    getInt s = TI (read i) : lexCmm cs where (i,cs) = span isDigit s
    isIdChar c = isAlpha c || isDigit c
    lx i = if isReservedWord i then TS i else TI i

  isSymb s = elem s $ words "++ -- == <= >= ++ { } = , ; + * - ( ) < >"

  isReservedWord w = elem w $ words "else if int main printInt return while"*
```

The error is:

```
file:{Hugs}\prog.hs:7 - Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the mentioned error of using an upper case `X` for a variable name, you have an indentation error, the defining equation of `lexCmm` is indented, but it ought to start in the leftmost column.

If you unindent that line

```
lexCmm :: String -> [Tok]
lexCmm x = case x of
```

and the definitions of `isSymb` and `isReservedWord` too, you will get some other errors.

The alternatives of the `case` expression must be indented further than the `case` keyword.

In

```
c:cs   | isAlpha c     -> getId s
c:cs   | isDigit c     -> getInt s
```

you use an entity `s` that is not in scope (so you should probably change the argument of `lexCmm` to `s`, or these two `s` to `x`.

```
getInt s = TI (read i) : lexCmm cs where (i,cs) = span isDigit s
```

strongly suggests that the constructor `TI` of `Tok` takes an `Int` argument, but

```
lx i = if isReservedWord i then TS i else TI i
```

tries to apply it to a `String`. You probably want `TI (read i)` there.

The following code, containing a quick mockup of a `Tok` type compiles:

```
module Toks where

import Data.Char

data Tok
    = TS String
    | TI Int
      deriving Show

main = do
   x <- readFile "progc.c"
   let resultado = lexCmm x
   print resultado

lexCmm :: String -> [Tok]
lexCmm s = case s of       -- No indentation for function definition
            c:cs   | isSpace c     -> lexCmm cs    -- alternatives indented further
            c:cs   | isAlpha c     -> getId s      -- than the `case', all to the same level
            c:cs   | isDigit c     -> getInt s
            c:d:cs | isSymb [c,d]  -> TS [c,d] : lexCmm cs
            c:cs   | isSymb [c]    -> TS [c]   : lexCmm cs
            _                      -> []  
      where  -- `where' indented less than the `case', so that it scopes over all alternatives
        getId s  = lx i : lexCmm cs where (i,cs) = span isIdChar s
        getInt s = TI (read i) : lexCmm cs where (i,cs) = span isDigit s
        isIdChar c = isAlpha c || isDigit c
        lx i = if isReservedWord i then TS i else TI (read i)

isSymb s = elem s $ words "++ -- == <= >= ++ { } = , ; + * - ( ) < >"

isReservedWord w = elem w $ words "else if int main printInt return while"
```

Comment: `isSymb` and `isReservedWord` are indented too far as well.

Comment: Ah, yes, you must indent the alternatives farther than the `c` of the `case`. I've auto-corrected that without thinking when I pasted it into my editor.

Comment: line 12: c:cs   | isSymb [c]    -> TS [c]   : lexCmm cs
line 13:  _                     -> []

Comment: I don't know what indentations you changed exactly how. I have added correctly indented code, with a few comments about the required indentation.

Comment: Ok, Daniel. I´ll test it. But before to do that I need to thank u.

Comment: The errors is gone. In the interpreter appears: Toks> what I type here?

Comment: You can type `main` there to run the `main` action. It will raise an error if there is no `progc.c` in the current directory, and I haven't checked whether the parser is well-behaved, so no guarantees about the result.

Comment: I´v tested and appears it: []. The progc.c and the .hs are in the same directory.

Comment: Let me guess, `prog.c` starts with `#include <...>` or a comment `//...` resp. `/* ... */`, right?

Comment: That means the .hs isn´t identifying the tokens ?

Comment: Yeah. Starts with #include<...>

Comment: Well, look at your `lexCmm` and what it does when it encounters a character it doesn't understand, such as `'#'` or `'/'`. You have to add a few more alternatives.

Comment: I´v included but appears the error: :main
[TS "#",TI 
Program error: Prelude.read: no parse

Comment: Oh, wait `lx i = if isReservedWord i then TS i else TI (read i)` doesn't really make sense in `getId`. That is only called if the first character is alphabetic, so it never can be read as an `Int`. Maybe you meant to use a different constructor of `Tok` there for a not-reserved word?

Comment: So how should be the constructor of Tok?

Comment: Well, I don't know. That depends on how much you want to be able to handle and how much of the syntax should be already reflected in the token list. Check your `Tok` type whether it already has an appropriate constructor. If it does, use that, otherwise, add one.

Comment: Thank u so much, Daniel. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell vars must begin with lower-case letters. Identifiers starting with upper-case letters are interpreted as types.

The upper-case `X` might be causing you problems here:

```
  lexCmm X = case X of
```

and here you are mixing lower and upper-case `x`:

```
  x <- readFile "progc.c"
  let resultado = lexCmm X
```

Replacing all these with lower-case `x` may fix your problems.

Comment: So the problem does indeed lie in the "case"... :)

Comment: I did this, but the problem is still in the line 7:

Comment: In this context `X` is being interpreted as a value constructor.

Comment: Is your indentation correct too? The lexCmm signature should line up with the definition line (can't post code to demonstrate, here but you have the definition on line 7 indented by 2 spaces)